# Polynomial $p\in\mathbb Q[x,y]$ such that $p(e,\pi)=0$.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, analytic-number-theory, irrational-numbers

Is there any polynomial $p\in\mathbb Q[x,y]$ that $p(e,\pi)=0$?

I was inspired by the fact that $\pi^4+\pi^5-e^6\approx 0$ and this lead me to the aforementioned question. Since there is no $p\in\mathbb Q[x]$ that $p(\pi),p(e)=0$ and the non-polynomial $f(e,\pi)=e^{i\pi}+1=0$. Is the statement in question a well-known result from somewhere? Any help would be appreciated, but please keep it as a (little as possible) hint so that I can study it further. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try $xy-1$ and any trascendental and its inverse. Not sure if this is what you want...

Comment: $\pi - \sqrt{\pi}^2 = 0$

Comment: Yeah, I forgot those, but what about $p(e,\pi)=0$?

Comment: I think, this is still an open problem, see also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33817/work-on-independence-of-pi-and-e)

Comment: We don't know if $\pi+e$, $\pi e$ are both transcendental, so it's an open problem.

Comment: Do there exist any real numbers $a, b$, such that $p(a,b) \neq 0: \forall p \in Q[x,y]$ ?

Comment: @SenZen Yes, but that should be a separate question

Answer (score 2):

In the comments already a few easy examples are mentioned. Just to list them in an answer here as well.

- You could take $p(x, y) = xy - 1$ and then pick any transcendental $x$ and set $y = 1/x$ (as suggested by Pedro Tamaroff).
- A similar strategy: take $p(x, y) = x - y^2$ and again pick any transcendental $x$ and now set $y = \sqrt{x}$.

You did also ask about a polynomial $p(x, y)$ such that $p(e, \pi) = 0$. This is still an open problem (as mentioned in the comments as well). It is conjectured that there is no such $p$. That is, that $e$ and $\pi$ are *algebraically independent*.

You might be interested in [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture), which is the following much more general statement.

> Let $z_1, \ldots, z_n \in \mathbb{C}$ be linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ then the transcendence degree of $(z_1, \ldots, z_n, e^{z_1}, \ldots, e^{z_n})$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$) is at least $n$.

So to see how this implies that $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent we can consider $z_1 = 1$ and $z_2 = \pi i$. Then by Schanuel's conjecture we would have that $(\pi i, 1, -1, e)$ has transcendence degree at least 2. Since $1$ and $-1$ are algebraic we have that $\pi i$ and $e$ must be algebraically independent, and hence $\pi$ and $e$ must be algebraically independent.

The conjecture is much more general than that and is studied a lot in model theory. This is also mentioned in the [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33817/work-on-independence-of-pi-and-e) that leoli1 links to. One nice thing to highlight there is that Zilber proved that there is indeed an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{B}$ with an exponential function (i.e. a group homomorphism from the additive group of $\mathbb{B}$ to the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{B}$), which satisfies Schanuel's conjecture.